# unexpected integer "1" wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 105

Tags: php, wordpress

Checked on my WordPress site today to find an HTTP 500 error.

```
2022/04/12 02:12:05 [error] 878#878: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected integer "1" in /var/www/domain.net/htdocs/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 105PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected integer "1" in /var/www/domain.net/htdocs/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 105" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.62.41, server: domain.net, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.net"
```

Line 105 in that WordPress file is:

```
$total                     = count( $entries )   1; // All the headers are one entry.
```

WordPress version 5.9.3

PHP version 8.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My local wordrpess has this as that line...

```
$total                     = count( $entries ) + 1; // All the headers are one entry.
```

I think your file has been tampered with

Comment: It's weird, because my line 107 also has that issue. Like the `+` was removed.

Comment: Are you saying if you look at the PHP in the file system the `+` is missing or present?

Comment: Basically, that entire file has the `+` removed. So weird, because I don't touch this site. I just replaced mo.php with a fresh one and the site is live again. So weird. So so weird.